# Changing URL appearance with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've been trying do write an .htaccess file, messing around with the `RewriteEngine`, that changes the last part of my url  `/index.php?lang=en` into just `/en` but so far i haven't had any success.

I tried different solutions that appear to have worked for other people here on SO but they didn't work for me, or i lack the knowledge to pull it off maybe...

Is it possible to achiev this with the .htaccess file?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Obviously it is possible to rewrite URLs. That is not your real question, is it? If you want us to help you have to be much more precise. Show your rewriting attempt so far (your rules) and tell exactly what happened, what was wrong with that and what you expected to happen. Also your http server and the relevant configuration that enables `.htaccess` style file interpretation could be important.

Comment: Obviously my question is "How do I change the Url from `/index.php?lang=en` to just `/en`, and by asking if it is even possible you can probably have an idea of how much I know about this... I didn't exactly MAKE any rules, i copied a bunch of lines from other people who wanted somewhat similar results, I turned on the `RewriteEngine` and tried lines like `RewriteRule   ^/(\S+).php?lang= /$1` that did nothing, probably because I don't know what I'm doing. I also tried `RewriteRule ^/index.php?lang=en $ /index/en` but i likely messed it up cause it also didn't yield any effect...

Comment: What introduction to url rewriting did you real? What documentation? Take a look at three things: 1. the urls you _send out_ are never changed by rewriting. Just send the correct urls out. rewriting only changes the way request _to the server_ are rewritten so that they can be processed. Some people expect that the other way round. 2. usage of `.htaccess` style files has to be enabled and configured on your http server. It is very well documented how to do this. 3. Enable rewrite logging, so that you see what is actually going on inside the rewrite module.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en$ index.php?lang=en
```